# Geometric representation of $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

We can regard $(\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$ as  rotation group of polygon.
However, is there any geometric representation of 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Z}_n^\times=\{\overline{a}\in \mathbb{Z}_n\mid {\rm gcd}(a,n)=1\}?
\end{align}

Comment: If addition is sliding / translating / rotating, then multiplication is most naturally seen as scaling.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$ can be visualized by constructing its cycle graph, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModuloMultiplicationGroup.html).